# Biblatex: Cannot get new BibliographyOption to work from document preamble

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to add a user option in biblatex to choose between two ways of displaying DOIs, but I can't get the option to take effect if it's issued by the user in the preamble.

To illustrate my problem, I prepared the MWE below. The `test.bbx` style loads `authoryear.bbx` and adds the option `compactdois`. If I set the option to true in the bbx file (either via `ExecuteBibliographyOptions` or via `settoggle`), DOIs are in fact displayed in a compact way. But issuing the commands in the document preamble in any of three ways (as a package option, via `ExecuteBibliographyOptions` or via `settoggle`) does not work.

What am I doing wrong? I would like the option to be able to be set in the document preamble, instead of once and for all in the `bbx` style.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{abbott-1997-NoteNatureWater,
  author       = {Abbott, Barbara},
  title        = {A Note on the Nature of {\emph{Water}}},
  journal      = {Mind},
  year         = 1997,
  volume       = 106,
  number       = 422,
  pages        = {311-319},
  doi          = {10.1093/mind/106.422.311}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bbx}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{authoryear}

\newtoggle{test:compactdois}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{compactdois}[true]{%
  \settoggle{test:compactdois}{#1}}

% \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{compactdois}                       % works
% \settoggle{test:compactdois}{true}                             % works

\iftoggle{test:compactdois}%
{\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
    \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space{#1}}}
{\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
    \url{https://doi.org/#1}}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=test]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=test,compactdois]{biblatex}  % no effect

% \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{compactdois}                       % no effect
% \settoggle{test:compactdois}{true}                             % no effect

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should put the test inside the FieldFormat, as it is now it is executed when the bbx is read.

Comment: Duh, thank you, @UlrikeFischer !